# Jetty - Jersey and Jar issue

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

i'm new in Jetty.

I always works on Tomcat but for this project i need to use an embedded jetty server.

My project structure is:

```
src
   package
      controller
      main
      ...

WebContent
   META-INF
   WEB-INF
      lib
      web.xml
```

I created a main inside package.main like this:

```
public class ServerLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new ServerLauncher().configureServer();
    }
    public void configureServer() throws Exception{
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setWar("WebContent");


        server.setHandler(webapp);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

My problem is:

When i execute it from eclipse, it correctly works.

When i export a RunnableJar File, it doesn't find me Webcontent:

```
SLF4J: This version of SLF4J requires log4j version 1.2.12 or later. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4j_version
- Logging initialized @248ms
- jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
- Web application not found WebContent
- Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7d19979e{/,null,null}{WebContent}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: WebContent
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at package.main.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:19)
- Started ServerConnector@53622a11{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
- Started @462ms
```

How can i correctly export the jar in order to execute jar correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the class with the Main method in it. You usually use a manifest file to do that.

Here is a link that may help:

http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html